# How do I add to the Wiki?

Tags: wordpress

I have been learning a lot about bugs and issues with CiviCRM with my recent install on Wordpress.  There are areas of the Wiki, such as [WordPress plugins/themes incompatible with CiviCRM](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=120029201) that I have some workarounds to contribute.  However, I am unable to add them to the Wiki, could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

When I try to login to the Wiki, I get the following error:

"Sorry, a network error occurred trying to log you in. Please try again, and contact your administrator if the problem persists."

Answer (score 2):

#### Expected behavior

If everything is working correctly, you *should* be able to edit the wiki by (1) logging in, and (2) clicking on an "Edit" link that displays with a pencil icon to the right of the green page title.

#### Getting help from an administrator

If you can't log in or you don't see the "Edit" link after logging in, then something might need to be fixed with your account or with the whole wiki. In this case it's best to ask one of the administrators for help by doing the following:

1. Log in to [Mattermost](https://chat.civicrm.org)
2. Go to the [infrastructure](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/infrastructure) channel
3. Post a message in that channel with the problem you're experiencing. Include your wiki username (if you have one) in the message. This is a relatively low-traffic channel that's monitored by administrators who will see your message soon, so there's no need to issue any notifications in your message.